# Hadoop mapreduce defining separators for streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

I'm using `Hadoop 2.7.1`

I'm really struggling to understand at what point in the **streaming** process sorts are applied, how you can change the sort order, and the separator. Reading the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) has confused me further since some config variables seem to be used interchangeably (c.f. `map.output.key.field.separator` used in the [partitioner example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Hadoop_Partitioner_Class) and `mapreduce.map.output.key.field.separator` in the [comparator example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Hadoop_Comparator_Class).

### My questions

1. At what point in the process are each of these configuration variables used and what exactly do they affect (and *is there a way by looking at them I can tell?*)
2. Additionally, what happens when they are used together? Do they over-ride each other?

   - `mapreduce.map.output.key.field.separator`
   - `map.output.key.field.separator`
   - `stream.map.output.field.separator`
   - `stream.num.map.output.key.fields`
   - `mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options`
   - `mapred.text.key.partitioner.options`
   - `mapreduce.fieldsel.data.field.separator`
   - `mapreduce.fieldsel.map.output.key.value.fields.spec`
   - `mapreduce.fieldsel.reduce.output.key.value.fields.spec`
   - `stream.reduce.input.field.separator`
   - `stream.num.reduce.input.fields`
   - `stream.reduce.output.field.separator`
   - `stream.num.reduce.output.fields`

Just search the [streaming documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) to see the context for their introduction. Most are (not contained in [mapred-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)).

I feel my confusion may be as a result of the distinction between separating the records into keys and values, and separating the key into multiple fields.

My understanding of the process (ignoring combiners for now):

1. Input data splits sent to the `Mappers`
2. `Mapper` outputs are split into (`key`, `value`) pairs and sent to the `Partitioner`
3. `Partitioner` sends the `Mapper` outputs to `Comparator` based on the key (*and the fields within the key?*)
4. The `Comparator` sorts each partition and sends it to a `Reducer`

Comment: What do you mean by *fields within the key*?

Comment: There are variables called `...key.field.separator` and `...output.field.separator`. I presume that the [partitioner example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Hadoop_Partitioner_Class) has outputs from the mapper like this: `11.12.1.2` --> {[`11`,`12`,`1`,`2`], `None`} i.e. keys with 4 fields and no value.